# Does the Flash run out of breath like a normal human when exercising?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014, the-flash

When a DC-universe human runs/exercises in general, much like our earth's humans they get out of breath and tire. Does this happen to the Flash? If so does he just have an insanely high fitness level?

In both the comics and the tv-shows/cartoons there have been instances where the Flash has not been able to push himself any more or stopped running and then had to have a sit down/rest.

Does the Flash get tired by performing "regular" exercise, as he does with running fast (not to be confused with time/dimension-travel, because then he isn't even a thing anymore, he's just energy using "running" as a vehicle so his mind can perceive and control what's happening).

If the Flash ran around the world perpetually, would he get tired like a regular athlete hitting their upper bound or not? If the Flash swam perpetually would he get tired as mentioned, or not?

An ideal answer would then show if there is a relationship between the two!

Comment: I remember Cisco and Catelyn discussing how many bees Barry would swallow when speed running. That means at least in the tv show he breathes while speed running.